# wav file to np.ndarry

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to read a .wav file into a np.ndarray, my issue is I am trying to replicate the .wav file to look like the following parameter

```py
X : np.ndarray, shape=(12,)
```

what I have is

```py
from scipy.io.wavfile import read

samplerate, data = read("./music/audio1.wav")
print(samplerate)
print(data)
```

output

```py
44100
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 ...
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

I would appreciate any guidance.
Thanks,

Comment: Seems like the data from your wave file is a stereo (2 channels) at 44.1 kHz. Meaning you have data of shape `(44100 * seconds, 2)`

Comment: I have a lot to learn...